# How to get real URL display on browser if there is proxy

Tags: c#, url, browser

I have an application, and has proxy url applied.

ProxyUrl: `myproxyurl/myapp`
InternalUrl: `myurl/myapp`

now in code, if use `Request.Url`, it will get `myurl/myapp`

how can i get `myproxyurl/myapp`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: refer to this link for clear explain why need that, but seem X-Forwarded-Host or X-Original-Host is not included in Azure App Proxy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/144558/azure-application-proxy-not-passing-x-forwarded-ho.html

Comment: here is another reference link https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/558

Comment: my workaround is to check Request.Headers whether contains proxy related key, if contains, means is access via proxy, then get pre-defined proxy url (maybe in db / appsettings)